# How to read and immediately discard some data in C++, without storing it?

Tags: c++

I was doing a competitive programming problem, where they required to input some value, which I didn't need to use in anyway. I just want to input this value, then immediately discard it, without storing it in any way.

In C, we could do it by doing : `scanf("%d %*c %d", &a, &b);` The middle character would be read and discarded without any  hassle.

What is the way to do this in C++?

Comment: Just read it into a dummy variable.

Comment: @NathanOliver-ReinstateMonica that's what I did initially, but then I thought if there was a way to just scan a value and throw it away. In C, there are options given like: scanf("%*c%d", &a)

Comment: It depends how you get the input and what format it has. `std::cin.ignore()` could be used if you know the number of characters to ignore.

Comment: @SHAFAYATMajumder why do you want to "throw the value away"?

Comment: @SHAFAYATMajumder The stream library can't handle that.  It requires a variable for each read operation.  You can use the `ignore` member function to skip characters, but this requires you to know how many characters to skip which can be problematic.

Comment: I think you're overthinking this honestly, just use a temp variable and it'll be gone once it's out of scope.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux, it would be a integer variable, actually 0. I have to ignore this 0.

Comment: @FMashiro actually I have to ignore that value, but still have to read it before I give the output

Comment: @Rietty, yes, I am actually overthinking for no reason

Comment: There's a practical reason why this isn't possible in C++. `printf` knows how to parse all format specifiers. But in C++, `operator<<` is a set of overloads. There's no format specifier. Thus you need a dummy variable to do overload resolution.

Answer (score 0):

You might add extra layer to have it, something like:

```
template <typename T>
struct discarded
{};

template <typename T>
std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& is, discarded<T>)
{
    T t;
    return is >> t;
}
```

and then

```
int a;
int c;

std::cin >> a >> discarded<int>() >> c;
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/519U5m)

Answer (score -1):

if you want to use the the variable's value only once, use it and then use same variable to store some other value(overwrite it, its same as discarding value of variable),anyway local variable's scope is limited to particular block only.